# Send email task with correct context

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, celery, celery-task

This code is my celery worker  script:

```
from app import celery, create_app
app = create_app('default')
app.app_context().push()
```

When I try to run the worker I will get into this error:

```
File "/home/vagrant/myproject/venv/app/mymail.py", line 29, in send_email_celery
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 126, in render_template
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 716, in update_template_context
    context.update(func())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My question is how can I send the email task, when using a worker in celery.

**mymail.py**

```
from flask import current_app, render_template
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from . import mail, celery

@celery.task
def send_async_email_celery(msg):
    mail.send(msg)

def send_email_celery(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(subject, sender=app.config['MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    send_async_email_celery.delay(msg)
```

**__init__**

```
...

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    redis_store.init_app(app)

    from .users import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

Apparently there is some conflict between the blueprint and worker. Remove the blueprint is not an option, if possible, due the custom filters that I need to use in email template.

Comment: I don't follow the reasoning here. Do you want the celery worker to register a blueprint? Sounds backwards to me, I would expect a blueprint to register celery tasks, not the other way around. Could you maybe explain what the blueprint is supposed to do and what the celery worker is supposed to do?

Comment: also, what's in your template?

Comment: @user3012759 even with an empty template (just for debugging), I will get the error. So the problem is not the template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found what is the reason of the problem after some debug with this [code](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky-with-celery).

I have a `app_context_processor` that will not return any result.

```
@mod.app_context_processor
def last_reputation_changes():
    if current_user:
        #code
        return dict(reputation='xxx')
```

When sending the email the `current_user` will need an `else` case to return something, since `current_user` from `from flask.ext.login import current_user` is not defined. Basically I only need something like this.

```
def last_reputation_changes():
    if current_user:
        #code
        return dict(reputation='xxx')
    else:
        return dict(reputation=None)
```

So the problem is not related with celery, but with the flask login integration.